Tesseract Code Execution Cannot Proceed, libcurl.dll
I'm trying to read text from images with Tesseract. I downloaded from here and installed in C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR, which was the default in the installer. When I try this in python:
image = Image.open(path); pytesseract.image_to_string(image), I keep getting the following issue:
tesseract.exe - System Error
The code execution cannot proceed because libcurl.dll was not found.
Reinstalling the program may fix this problem`

I've tried reinstalling the program to no avail. I also downloaded the libcurl.dll file from online (here and from dllme) and placed it the same directory as tesseract.exe. I also tried adding it to PATH, but still nothing works. Why doesn't this work after fresh installs? Thanks.
